# Percentage based width jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a simple sliding panel script for a website where I have 3 categories, each one is a panel but I'm having a hard time using percentage for the width.

I've create d jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/estebanrao/FZ6ea/

HTML:

```
<div class="cat-selector">
    <a href="#" class="cat-s-notebooks">Notebooks</a>
    <a href="#" class="cat-s-desktops">Desktops</a>
    <a href="#" class="cat-s-smartphones">Smartphones</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cat-selector {
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.cat-selector > a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 33%;
}
.cat-s-notebooks {
    background: red;
}
.cat-s-desktops {
    background: green;
}
.cat-s-smartphones {
    background: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.cat-selector')
    .on('mouseenter', 'a', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '39%',
    }, 300, 'swing')
    $(this).siblings('a').animate({
        width: '30%',
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 300, 'swing')
})
    .on('mouseleave', 'a', function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '33%',
    }, 300, 'swing')
    $(this).siblings('a').stop().animate({
        width: '33%',
        opacity: 1
    }, 300, 'swing')
});
```

If you take a look at the example you'll notice that the total width of the 3 panels is always 99%. The thing is that I want this size to always match the closes number to 100% as possible.

I tried using decimals (.33) but it only got worse.
I also tried getting the total width of the window and make the math from there but it was also a failed attempt.

Is there anything I'm missing to achieve the 100% percentage (or decimal closest)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to get it to 100% without it messing up but `33.2%` seems to work at least on chrome.. It could work differently for different browsers though.. Is there a reason why `33%` isn't good enough?  I'm curious to see if anyone knows why it messes up though.. I have a feeling its because of the way the browser handles borders etc..

Comment: not sure if this works for you but you can cheat a bit by wrapping in a parent that is set to 100% with overflow hidden. Then you can go slightly over 100% total for your elements without scrollbar issues

Comment: Thanks! I ended up refining the percentage inside a div with 100% width, hidden overflow and nowrap whitespace (since items are <a> with inline-block display) so they won't collapse

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I just added a container div

```
<div class="cat-selector-container">
```

With css properties

```
.cat-selector-container { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; }
```

I don't really NEED that container for this, I could just add this css to my the .cat-selector div but since I have some top padding I added this extra div to avoid scroll bars.